# Why does pytorch treat network classes like functions?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

While looking at PyTorch tutorials, they use classes they define like functions.

e.g.

```
#Making an instance of the class NeuralNetwork
model = NeuralNetwork()
```

```
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

I wasn't aware that this could be done in python, and am therefore confused about what is going on, and what is getting called. I know that the `forward()` function (a function necessary to any class that inherits from nn.Module) is the movement of data through the neural network, but i'm not sure when that gets called and how `model(x)` is working. Also, while trying to find an answer, I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952664/how-do-i-predict-using-a-pytorch-model), where a contributor said "A pytorch model is a function. You provide it with appropriately defined input, and it returns an output. If you just want to visually inspect the output given a specific input image, simply call it:". This left me more confused, because the model is a class, right?

Comment: It appears that `NeuralNetwork()` returns something that is _callable_.  Maybe it's a function, or maybe it is a class object (but not a class _instance_).

Comment: Everything in Python is an object, including classes and functions.  A function is just an object that implements `__call__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few layers to this. First, the pure python layer:

Python objects have various [dunder methods](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/dunder-methods) (double underscore) such as `__init__`, `__repr__`, and others. One such method is `__call__`. If you call a python object like a function, it invokes the `__call__` method of the object class.

```py
class MyClass
    __call__(self, input):
        return print(input)

my_class = MyClass()

# doing this
my_class(5)

# is the same as 
my_class.__call__(5)
```

Now the pytorch layer:

Pytorch `nn.Module` classes use the `__call__` method to invoke the module. The full implementation of what happens is in the `nn.Module._call_impl` function ([link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1513)).

`nn.Module._call_impl` makes use of the `forward` method you implement in your custom module. The full `_call_impl` logic involves things that happen both before and after `forward`. Pytorch is designed in a way to abstract these things from the user - you only need to implement your isolated `forward` logic and the rest should be handled for you.

Now the ML theory layer:

When someone says `A pytorch model is a function`, what they mean is ML models are mathematical functions. They are not referring to the programming level class/function distinction.

Now a deeper pytorch layer:

Most pytorch classes are actually wrappers around a functional implementation at the C/Cuda level. For example, look at the `forward` method of `nn.Conv2d`. The forward function of the class object actually calls `nn.functional.conv2d`, which in turn calls the lower level implementation of the convolution. The functional versions of modules pass both the inputs and weights from the module itself.

Comment: So if __call__ is not defined in a class like NerualNetwork, does it inherit __call__ from its parent? NeuralNetwork doesn’t include any __call__ definition.

Comment: Read about [inheritance](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/) in python. `NerualNetwork` sub-classes `nn.Module` (I assume), so it inherits `__call__` from `nn.Module`

Comment: NeuralNetwork does inherit from nn.Module, sorry for not mentioning. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Even if the model is a class, it can be implemented to be callable like a function.

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#callable-types):

> 3.2.8. Callable types
>
> These are the types to which the function call operation [...] can be applied:
>
> 3.2.8.1. User-defined functions
>
> A user-defined function object is created by a function definition.
>
> [...]
>
> 3.2.8.9. Class Instances
>
> Instances of arbitrary classes can be made callable by defining a [`__call__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-callable-objects) method in their class.

So the following is valid Python code:

```py
class MyCustomClass:
    def __call__(self, a):
        print(f'Printing {a}')

c = MyCustomClass()
c(42)    # Outputs `Printing 42`
```